# Force Cortana to Listen - Is there any other way than clicking with mouse?

Tags: c#, cortana

I'm creating a program to automatize my home.

But if there is noise in the background, or music is playing, Cortana doesn't response to the "Hey Cortana" phrase.

Is there any way to force Cortana to listening through a C# program with `TCPlistener` to activate Cortana on a PC with an app on mobile or another device?

Answer (score 0):

Cortana does not officially support deep linking or proactive push notifications. Feel free to "provide feedback" via the cortana feedback button to add this feature.

Also, desktop PCs don't implement the latest, greatest noise cancellation or cocktail party filtering. You could suggest that too, but its bleeding edge AI.